# Can I install adobe Illustrator cs6 on 32-bit mac

Tags: adobe, 32-bit

I have mac book pro, Processor: 2.16 Ghz intel Core Duo, Memory: 1 GB 667 Mhz DDR2 SDRAM, Model Identifier: MacBookPro1,2, Total Number Of Cores: 2, Boot ROM Version: MBP12.0061.B03.

I tried to install adobe illustrator cs6 on it but I got forbidden mark on the application.

Is there is any luck with that, or I have to buy new mac, I hope not

Thanks

Comment: This will be a comment, but because of lack of reputation I couldn´t. Please specify your correct macbook pro version. To do this please click at the apple on the left upper corner, than press ALT key and choose "system informations" - please write what you could see under "model identification". The ofter thing: Which version of OSX do you use?

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the system requirements on the [Adobe web site](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/policy-pricing/cs6-system-requirements.html) I could say: No, you can´t use Adobe CS6 Illustrator with your Mac because of the lack of RAM (1GB instead of 2GB) and no 64bit processor as Apple said it on your [support document](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3696).

Comment: Thank you, your answer unfortunately correct, and I am in a problem to buy new mac

Comment: is there is a way to convert the application to 32-bit?

Comment: No, you can´t convert the application and for Mac only exists a 64bit version of Adobe CS6.